# How to verify events in kinesis stream as part of integration tests?

Tags: integration-testing, amazon-kinesis

I am writing an integration test to verify that data is pushed to kinesis stream. The pipeline works as below:

api gateway --> lambda --> kinesis

so when I call the endpoint, I should be able to see the events in kinesis stream. I am using the below code to read data from kinesis:

```
    @Test
    fun testWhenEventsArePublishedToKinesis() {
        val url = URL("$host/v1/events}")
        val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.requestMethod = "POST"
        connection.doOutput = true

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/text")
        connection.setRequestProperty("foo-A", "A")
        connection.setRequestProperty("foo-B", "B")
        connection.setRequestProperty("foo-C", "2")

        val data = "{\"data\":[{\"A\":\"1\",\"B\":\"C\",\"timestamp\":\"12345\"}]}"

        val outputStream = connection.outputStream
        val writer = OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8")
        writer.write(data)
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()

      
        val shardIteratorRequest = GetShardIteratorRequest
            .builder()
            .streamARN(streamARN)
            .shardId("shardId-000000000000")
            .shardIteratorType(ShardIteratorType.LATEST)
            .build()
        val shardIterator = kinesisClient
            .getShardIterator(shardIteratorRequest)
        val getRecordsRequest = GetRecordsRequest
            .builder()
            .streamARN(streamARN)
            .shardIterator(shardIterator.shardIterator())
            .build()

        var records = kinesisClient.getRecords(getRecordsRequest)
        println(records.records())

    }
```

The problem is when I run the above code I get empty array of `records` although data is in the stream. My guess is that the shard iterator points to empty data so thats why I get empty records. Is there any other way I can verify data in kinesis.